# Getting shadow text to work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, dropshadow

After finding a similar question on SO, I still am having problems.  Here is my CSS:

```
        .title {
            position:absolute;
            bg-color:#FF0000;
            z-index:10;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            font-size:250%;
            color: #FCD116;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #555;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#555, offx=1, offy=1);
            zoom:1
        }
```

In Google Chrome, the shadow is only offset by about 2 pixels.  This is exactly what I want.  In IE, however, the shadows are super far away (relative to what I want) and chunky.  I've set the offx and offy to one.  Why isn't this working?  I've never used this method before, I just found it now while looking at the suggestions on SO with my title.

**AS A SIDE NOTE**

While I am asking, does anybody know how to get IE to let me do transparent images?  I tried to put a semi transparent image (a button with a drop shadow) but the shadow is dark black and it gives the appearance that the quality has been compromised.  I'll award points for this question (if answered) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue - you need to use a full 6-character HEX value - i.e. #555555 - inside the filter.

Side issue - personally I've found [Drew Diller's belated_png script](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) to be a quick and reliable solution. Drop in the script, and apply a png_bg class to anything you want to have alpha transparency.

PS - http://jsfiddle.net/peXwY/

```
.title {
    position:absolute;
    bg-color:#FF0000;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:250%;
    color: #FCD116;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #555;
    Filter: DropShadow(Color=#555555, OffX=2, OffY=2, Positive=1);
    zoom:1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some good information for your side note... Also, take a look at the "sleight" reference towards the bottom: http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

As for the main issue, considering messing with the z-index of .title. I recall having issues with it in IE several months ago, and it was because of the way IE was ordering the vertical objects on the page.

Comment: I've messed around with the z-index to no avail.  Your transparency solution worked like a charm... Thanks so much :)

Comment: Also, filter: Shadow appears to be working well for me. Check out some examples here: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows